# Why doesn't my token redirect to the previous url?

Tags: users, tokens, redirection

I thought I could use the following code:

```
<a href="user/login?destination=<?php print token_replace('[current-page:url]'); ?>a link</a>
```

to redirect users to the page they were on after log in, but it doesn't seem to work.

I can see the correct url on the login page, e.g.:

> mysite/user/login?destination=the url of the page I was on

but when I login I am still redirected to `mysite/users/my` user name.

Comment: Where are you placing the code?

Comment: I'm placing the code in a block, where all the other code works ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Redirect to previous drupal page after login, you can try this.

```
print l("Login","user/login",array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));
```

see [drupal_get_destination](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_destination/7)

Comment: Top tip, thanks, but actually my 'link' is an image... how would I call the image instead of the "Login" text?

Comment: thanks @nikhil-m I found out that you can put an image in a l() by using 'html' => true, Thanks to https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7 so what i ended up with is: print l('<img src="path-to-image.png" title="A title here">',"user/login",array('query' => drupal_get_destination(), 'html' => true, ));

Comment: @user2337605 thanks for the info. i will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Token Filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) module and the following code should work:

```
<a href="user/login?destination=[site:current-page:path]">a link</a>
```

Make sure that the token filter is available in the text format you are using.