# redirect user to page where they clicked an "add node" link

Tags: redirection

In several places on my site I use an "add node" link that lets users add a node (I'm using organic groups).  After saving the node, I'd like to redirect users back to the page on which they clicked the "add node" link.

I know how to redirect users to a specific page after saving a node, but that doesn't work in this case, as the add link shows up on several pages.

I've tried setting $form_state['redirect'] = false, but that also doesn't help as it puts users back in the node edit page.

Would be wonderful if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

EDIT: 2 minutes after I posted this I came up with the following:  `<a href="node/add/contact?destination=node/52">Add Contact</a>`

This redirects the user to node 52, which happens to be the group page on which this add link lives.  This is a step in the right direction.  Would be even better if I could use a token in the link.

Comment: Please check [Why doesn't my token redirect to the previous url?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75068/why-doesnt-my-token-redirect-to-the-url).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Token Filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) module and the following code should work:

```
<a href="node/add/contact?destination=[site:current-page:path]">Add Contact</a>
```

Make sure that the token filter is available in the text format you are using.